# Fixed, Sticky Element Stopped at Footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sticky

I am using jSticky javascript to float an element until it scrolls to a stopper (In this case, its the footer) and then it stops.

This works great for non-fixed elements but I am not sure how to get this accomplished with the element being fixed to the lower right of the browser window. I want it about 15px away from the bottom and right side of the viewport. Any ideas?

http://phostercreative.com/test/

Brian

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to move the play icon to 15px away from the bottom right of the page, and have it disappear when the footer is reached?

The easiest way to go about that is to make the button *itself* positioned absolutely:

```
.fixed-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

Note that `position: absolute` will make it not stop at the footer. To get around that, you can use `float: right`, but you would need to modify jSticky to work from `bottom` rather than `top`. I'm not familiar with jSticky, but changing that would allow the desired result.

Hope this helps! :)